Expecting end of line, etc but found number
I wrote this but getting an expecting end of line, etc, but found number...
   on run {input, parameters}
     tell application "System Events"
      repeat 2 times
        keystroke "'" using {control down}
        delay 0.1
        keystroke "q"
        delay 0.1
        keycode 124
        delay 0.1
        keystroke "b" using {command down}
        delay 0.1
      end repeat
     end tell
    end run


The key code command should be 2 words.
